# Tracking online status?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, web-applications

I am quite new to web development and am working on this social networking site.

Now I want to add functionality to show if a person is online.

Now one of the ways I figure out doing this is by keeping online status bit in the database.

My question is how to do it dynamically. Say the page is loaded and a user (say connection) comes online. How do I dynamically change status of that connection on that page.

I wanted to know if there are any tools(libraries) available for this type of tracking. My site is in python using django framework. I think something can be done using javascript/ jquery . I want to know if I am going in the right direction or is there anything  else I should look into?

Comment: Database would be bit of an overkill IMO. Look into in-memory solutions like Redis etc.

Comment: Since your connection to server is based on request-response you can never know if the user is still online, only when was the last time he was online. See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12768482/1247955) answer helps you.

Comment: Although an in-memory solution would work, if you're already using django I believe that simply adding an 'online' boolean field would be simpler than setting up an entirely new memory storage system.

Comment: You can find a complete solution for django [here](http://mpcabd.igeex.biz/get-online-users-in-django/). Granted some of the code is a bit weird, but the concept of writing a simple custom middleware is correct.

Comment: @Bula Thanks for the guidance. I will keep this in mind while writing this application.

Comment: @dgel Thanks for the link. I think this is the closest to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new model with a `last_activity` `DateTimeField` and a `OneToOneField` to `User`. Alternatively, if you are subclassing `User`, using a custom `User` in django 1.5, or using a user profile, just add the field to that model.

Write a custom middleware that automatically updates the `last_activity` field for each user on every request.

Write an `is_online` method in one of your models that uses a timedelta to determine a user's inactivity period to return a boolean for whether they are online. For example, if their `last_activity` was more than 15 minutes ago, return `False`.

Write a view that is polled through jQuery ajax to return a particular user's online status.

Answer (score 0):

As Sanjay says, prefer using memory solutions (online statuses have a quite brief use) like the Django cache (Redis or Memcache).

If you want a simple way of updating the online status of an user on an already loaded web page, use any lib like jQuery, AJAX-poll an URL giving the status of an user, and then update the tiny bit of your page showing your wanted status.
Don't poll this page too often, once every 15 seconds seems reasonable.